# Return row with column values or missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query as follows in latest version MS-SQL:

`SELECT s.* FROM catalogue l INNER JOIN uom s ON s.SAPUom = l.Uom AND l.Id = 5`

with an output as follows

[image]

If there is a CompId and SupplierId uom mapping in the table (row 2) bring back that one **else** bring back the uom that is NULL (row 1)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row, then one method uses `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) s.*
FROM catalogue l INNER JOIN 
     uom s
     ON s.SAPUom = l.Uom AND l.Id = 5
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN compid is not null OR supplierid is not null THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

Comment: Thank Gordon that answered the question. Could I ask a extention to the question? 
If i was going to use a IN operator like (which is what I am actually doing) how would you extend that?
SELECT TOP (1) s.* FROM catalogue l INNER JOIN uom s ON s.SAPUom = l.Uom AND l.Id IN (4,5) ORDER BY (CASE WHEN compid is not null OR supplierid is not null THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)? Can open another question if you would prefer

Comment: @Kevin . . . That would be easier to follow in another question.